# Anatomically Correct Strider

Tags: internal-consistency, anatomy, lava, video-games

This is a submission for the [Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series/2798#2798])

To celebrate the upcoming Nether update for Minecraft, I've decided to ask, what an anatomically correct Strider would look like?

[image]

Based on all the available data we know that Striders:

- Are 5.5 ft tall.
- Are herbivores eating the fungi that exist in the Nether (an alternate dimension filled with lava and various dangerous creatures, it is akin to the Christian concept of Hell.)
- Move in herds.
- Are bipedal, and seemingly lack arms.
- Can walk on lava.
- Thrive in hot temperatures (shivering when out side of lava).
- Can support the weight of a fully grow human.
- Are red in coloration

Given these characteristics, could such a creature realistically exist?

Comment: What is a nether? Why is it scheduled to be updated? And, except for the magical lava part and the red coloration, how are they different from ordinary ostriches, emus and cassowaries?

Comment: @AlexP the nether is a dimension in minecraft which lacks any water a has vast lava seas

Comment: @icewar1908 I think what AlexP is trying to say is that it is not immediately obvious to non-Minecraft players what the Nether is. With that in mind, I have added the necessary data in my edit.

Comment: Methinks the ACS rules should be updated to exclude video game constructs not based on literary creatures.

Comment: @JBH really i didn't think their was anything worng with this question seeing as their are many AC question based on video games

Comment: (a) The modified rules state that what people have done in the past cannot be used as precedent to break the modified rules. (b) Most video game creatures (especially anything from Minecraft and other highly simplistic games) fail to meet the description requirements of the rules. This one does. There's simply not enough description to rationalize the invention of evolution. From the rules: "We're willing to help, but we will not invent the creature and summon it into this world for you." IMO this is a good example of an under-defined entry (as all Minecraft creatures will be).

Comment: One more thing. This is a place to help people build worlds, not indulge in whims. There are clear precedents in Meta that this forum is NOT for extending pre-existing or commercial worlds (which Minecraft clearly is). There are other forums for that purpose. I've noticed over the last 6 months a number of complaints that ACS is getting muddied by low-quality entries. I agree. This entry (and your others) should be closed if only because you're asking about someone else's world, not yours, and the result cannot be used to legally help (IMO) another author.

Comment: @JBH, I took the liberty of using your comment to start a discussion in Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**swimming in lava and red coloration**
Make them having a metallic structure not based on calcium but on iron so it can swim in lava without melting, everything must be covered in metal, even the eyes and the skin.

**shivers**
Oxygen harms them and they shake in reaction to pain. They breathe ammonia or other gases, that's why they like lava... Or maybe they don't need breathing at all, probably they digest food through fermentation.

The rest doesn't need much more alien like features, just make them herd iron giant chickens of hell that eat mushrooms.

Comment: You are completely ignoring the tags. There is no biology possible on lava.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica well, there's also no hell dimension with seas of lava... But life inside volcanoes is quite a thing, just extend the concept of extremophiles to an alien level